# Put data in WHERE clause condition without fetching it | And remove duplication in Left Join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have data with the following structure:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Software Engineer",
  "description": "bla.. bla.."
  "salary": 1000
  "skills_needed": [
     {
       name: "Golang"
     },
     {
       name: "React.Js"
     },
     {
       name: "Docker"
     }
  ]
}
```

> Context: Above is a job data from a table called `hirings` and it has
> a relation with a table called `skill_hirings` and `skills`. More context below.

How do I put `skills` on the WHERE clause without fetching it? I want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM hirings WHERE skill.name = '%Docker%';
```

I know the query above doesn't make sense, that's why I'm asking.

I've tried the `LEFT JOIN` query. But there is a problem, if the job has more than one skill then the result will duplicate as it is how `LEFT JOIN` works. More or less, here is the left join query that I've tried

```
SELECT h.id, h.name, h.description, h.salary FROM hirings h
LEFT JOIN skill_hirings sh ON sh.hiring_id = h.id
LEFT JOIN skills s ON s.id = sh.skill_id
WHERE s.name = '%Docker%';
```

And if I use a subquery in the where clause, it won't works because it will return more than one data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select * from hirings h
    where exists (select * from skill_hirings sh, skills s 
                  where s.id = sh.skill_id 
                  and sh.hiring_id = h.id 
                  and s.name = 'Docker')
```

Though I don't understand how can your query return multiple rows, unless you have multiple skills called 'Docker'. You probably wrote `where s.name LIKE '%Docker%'` instead of `where s.name = '%Docker%` ?

Another solution would be to add DISTINCT to your select statement, as in: `select distinct h.id, h.name, h.description, h.salary from ...`

Also when using LIKE operator, you probably want to use it like this `lower(s.name) like '%docker%'` in order to make it case insensitive.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` one probably could help me. But it would check all the selected columns if they're completely the same to be removed from the result right? How do I DISTINCT only one or two columns while SELECTing another column at the same time

Comment: That doesnt make much sense. Post an example of the desired output. Maybe you need GROUP BY

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I just realized that the whole column that duplicates are of course would be completely the same, what is wrong with me. Thank you btw!